# What is the default behaviour for Ranges with the same beginning and end?

Tags: ruby

I created a method which ran a loop for the range `(1...array.length)`. The output was always correct with length greater than 1, but whenever I just had an array of one character `i.e ['a']` the output still came out correct. The reason this worries me is because I'm not sure how the program knows not to index a nil array object...`arr[1]` in the case of a length of one.

```
def vowels_in_order?(word)  
  vowels = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  (1...vowels.length).each { |index| return false if vowels[index] < vowels[index-1]}
  return true
end
```

Therefore I'm wondering if there is a default behavior for ranges, which didn't cause the loop to crash. Or possibly, does it have to do with my method, as that would be insightful as well.

Here is an example of how the loop should technically crash:

```
2.1.0 :1116 > word = "a"
 => "a" 
2.1.0 :1117 > word[1] < word[0]
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb#1):1117
```

Comment: why should the loop crash if the beginning and end are same?

Comment: what are you trying to do in the loop? are you checking if the vowels are in the alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes, but not really the point of my question. I added the reason it should crash in my question since the comment formatting was not playing well.

Comment: @Maksim you could try to write to your console when iterating over the range 1...1 and see what happens.

Comment: '2.1.0 :1118 > (1...1).each { |x| puts x}
 => 1...1 ' ...that doesn't really do me any good. I still can't figure out why the loop is behaving the way it does.

Comment: How about `(1...1).each {|x| puts "hello" }`

Comment: your code is flawed to handle nil Classes. hence it is breaking. rewrite the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html). Please refer to that page for more detailed documentation for ranges (first paragraph should help you)

```
Ranges constructed using .. run from the start to the end inclusively. 
Those created using ... exclude the end value.
```

Answer (score 3):

`(1...1)` and `(1...0)` are both empty (contain no elements), so calling `each` on them does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's head to irb:

`irb(main):001:0> (1...1).to_a
=> []`

So we have an empty array

Now let's look at your code

```
def vowels_in_order?(word)  
  vowels = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  (1...vowels.length).each { |index| return false if vowels[index] < vowels[index-1]}
  return true
end
```

This can be rewritten (for the case that vowels.length == 1):

```
def vowels_in_order?(word)  
  vowels = word.scan(/[aeiou]/)
  [].each { |index| return false if vowels[index] < vowels[index-1]}
  return true
end
```

You can now see that you are iterating over an empty array. Therefore the code in the `{ |index| return false if vowels[index] < vowels[index-1]}` block is never run. We can test this with

`irb(main):027:0> [].each { |i| puts "hello"}
=> []`

Edited: Didn't realize you were using `...` instead of `..`

Answer (score 1):

These are things to consider when using Ranges.

These are reasonable range declarations:

```
(1 .. 1).to_a   # => [1]
(1 .. 2).to_a   # => [1, 2]
(1 ... 2).to_a  # => [1]
```

Notice that `1 .. 1` is equivalent to `1 ... 2`.

These are *not* reasonable range declarations but their results are equivalent:

```
(1 .. 0).to_a   # => []
(1 ... 1).to_a  # => []
```

And, in both cases, Ruby will do nothing because a range must start with a beginning value that is the less-than or equal to the ending value.

From [the Range documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html):

> A Range represents an interval—a set of values with a beginning and an end. Ranges may be constructed using the s..e and s...e literals, or with ::new. Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using ... exclude the end value. When used as an iterator, ranges return each value in the sequence.

... and ...

> ... *Methods that treat the range as a sequence (#each and methods inherited from Enumerable) expect the begin object to implement a succ method to return the next object in sequence.*

`1.succ # => 2` which immediately causes the iterations over the range to exit.

Use `..` over `...`. `...` is the source of many errors and maintenance problems due to behavior equivalence of `1 ... 2` acting like `(1) .. (2 - 1)`. People's eyes are terrible at quickly seeing and recognizing when `...` is used instead of `..`. *IF* you insist on using `...`, then format your code for legibitity and use whitespace to give the eyes something to latch onto.

```
1 .. 1
```

is more readable than:

```
1..1
```

or:

```
1...2
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have some misconception about what the syntax `a...b` to create a range actually does. Have a look at [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html), where this syntax is explained.

### Definition:

> A Range represents an interval—a set of values with a beginning and an end. Ranges may be constructed using the s..e and s...e literals, or with ::new. Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using ... exclude the end value. When used as an iterator, ranges return each value in the sequence.

### Example:

```
(-1..-5).to_a      #=> []
(-5..-1).to_a      #=> [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
('a'..'e').to_a    #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
('a'...'e').to_a   #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```